# Split a large GeoTIFF into smaller regions with Python and GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have quite a large GeoTIFF-file (compressed 50MB but unpacked 6GB) and want to split it into several smaller regional files.

I am using Python, and as I am a new GDAL user I do not really have an idea how to start. Is gdalwarp ChunkAndWarpImage the function I am looking for? And how do I apply it in Python? Can I or must I define the region size?

Comment: as a remark, using vrt (see gdal_buildvrt) files would probably be the best solution for further processing of your data.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need GDAL's Python module to do this, you can use the gdal_translate program to subset images: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html. See the -srcwin and -projwin options.

Answer (score 5):

You can indeed use gdal_translate, but if you don't want to use the GDAL command line tool or have to make system call outs from Python, you can use something like the following code to create a n*n grid of rasters for a given input raster:

```
  def get_extent(dataset):

    cols = dataset.RasterXSize
    rows = dataset.RasterYSize
    transform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
    minx = transform[0]
    maxx = transform[0] + cols * transform[1] + rows * transform[2]

    miny = transform[3] + cols * transform[4] + rows * transform[5]
    maxy = transform[3]

    return {
            "minX": str(minx), "maxX": str(maxx),
            "minY": str(miny), "maxY": str(maxy),
            "cols": str(cols), "rows": str(rows)
            }

def create_tiles(minx, miny, maxx, maxy, n):
    width = maxx - minx
    height = maxy - miny

    matrix = []

    for j in range(n, 0, -1):
        for i in range(0, n):

            ulx = minx + (width/n) * i # 10/5 * 1
            uly = miny + (height/n) * j # 10/5 * 1

            lrx = minx + (width/n) * (i + 1)
            lry = miny + (height/n) * (j - 1)
            matrix.append([[ulx, uly], [lrx, lry]])

    return matrix


def split(file_name, n):
    raw_file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_name))[0].replace("_downsample", "")
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    dataset = gdal.Open(file_name)
    band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
    transform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()

    extent = get_extent(dataset)

    cols = int(extent["cols"])
    rows = int(extent["rows"])

    print "Columns: ", cols
    print "Rows: ", rows

    minx = float(extent["minX"])
    maxx = float(extent["maxX"])
    miny = float(extent["minY"])
    maxy = float(extent["maxY"])

    width = maxx - minx
    height = maxy - miny

    output_path = os.path.join("data", raw_file_name)
    if not os.path.exists(output_path):
        os.makedirs(output_path)

    print "GCD", gcd(round(width, 0), round(height, 0))
    print "Width", width
    print "height", height


    tiles = create_tiles(minx, miny, maxx, maxy, n)
    transform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
    xOrigin = transform[0]
    yOrigin = transform[3]
    pixelWidth = transform[1]
    pixelHeight = -transform[5]

    print xOrigin, yOrigin

    tile_num = 0
    for tile in tiles:

        minx = tile[0][0]
        maxx = tile[1][0]
        miny = tile[1][1]
        maxy = tile[0][1]

        p1 = (minx, maxy)
        p2 = (maxx, miny)

        i1 = int((p1[0] - xOrigin) / pixelWidth)
        j1 = int((yOrigin - p1[1])  / pixelHeight)
        i2 = int((p2[0] - xOrigin) / pixelWidth)
        j2 = int((yOrigin - p2[1]) / pixelHeight)

        print i1, j1
        print i2, j2

        new_cols = i2-i1
        new_rows = j2-j1

        data = band.ReadAsArray(i1, j1, new_cols, new_rows)

        #print data

        new_x = xOrigin + i1*pixelWidth
        new_y = yOrigin - j1*pixelHeight

        print new_x, new_y

        new_transform = (new_x, transform[1], transform[2], new_y, transform[4], transform[5])

        output_file_base = raw_file_name + "_" + str(tile_num) + ".tif"
        output_file = os.path.join("data", raw_file_name, output_file_base)

        dst_ds = driver.Create(output_file,
                               new_cols,
                               new_rows,
                               1,
                               gdal.GDT_Float32)

        #writting output raster
        dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray( data )

        tif_metadata = {
            "minX": str(minx), "maxX": str(maxx),
            "minY": str(miny), "maxY": str(maxy)
        }
        dst_ds.SetMetadata(tif_metadata)

        #setting extension of output raster
        # top left x, w-e pixel resolution, rotation, top left y, rotation, n-s pixel resolution
        dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(new_transform)

        wkt = dataset.GetProjection()

        # setting spatial reference of output raster
        srs = osr.SpatialReference()
        srs.ImportFromWkt(wkt)
        dst_ds.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )

        #Close output raster dataset
        dst_ds = None

        tile_num += 1

    dataset = None
```

This builds on this excellent answer: [GDAL Python cut geotiff image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199477/gdal-python-cut-geotiff-image)

Comment: Great answer! Also works for images with more than one `RasterBand` but you have to modify it: Retrieve the other bands (`bandN = dataset.GetRasterBand(n)`) in a similar fashion and then write them (`dst_ds.GetRasterBand(n).WriteArray( dataN )`) to the output. Make sure to add `n` to the `driver.Create()` argument to specify the number of bands.